# Import: Value for 'country_of_manufacture' attribute contains incorrect value but I just exported it... sanity check for 2.4.4

Tags: importexport, magento2.4.4, product-import

I am confident I am not going crazy - but has anyone else experienced odd behaviour with the Magento 2 imports?

I am importing data sheets and it is flagging up country_of_manufacture as having incorrect values for lines containing:

```
Taiwan, Province of China
```

Now the reason I am confident that there is something odd happening - if I export products I imported a few days ago the value is exported as Taiwan, Province of China & if I then try to import the export sheet it gives me the same error.

There have been 0 modules installed between these 2 imports etc so there has to be something fundamental happening?
Has anyone else experienced this? Is it an out of date index etc?

I will keep trying to diagnose the problem but perhaps someone has already had the problem and found the solution.